# Ubuntu server Installation boot problem

Tags: grub-efi

I've got a dl380 g9 server with RAID 1 and it's use a storage server
I've downloaded Ubuntu from here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
It's installed with no problem But it won't boot.
Bios is UEFI and I used USB to install it
I think the problem is with bootloader.
If the problem is with bootloader how can I use boot-repair because the server should not connect to internet
If it isn't with the bootloader what is it?

Comment: "It won't boot" is a lot like saying "My car won't start" - there could be a hundred possibilities. Please acquire more data about what does (and does not) occur during boot so we can rule out the possibilities and help you better. Hook up a display to your server and watch the boot messages.

Comment: @user535733 it's a dual boot with esxi and each time I restart the system boot esxi nevertheless Ubuntu has higher priority in boot order